# How to connect tensoflow to jupyter notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed `Anaconda` with `jupyter notebook` in `/home/serg/anaconda/bin` and installed `tensoflow` in `./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow`. My operation system is `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Is it possible to use `tensorflow` in `jupyter notebook` via changing some configuration in `anaconda` or `jupyter`?

P.S.: I know it is possible for most python IDE, but I need to do it with `jupyter notebook` in `anaconda`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood my problem: just used `anaconda promts` and installed tensoflow right here. Then I run `jupyter notebook` in `anaconda promts` and imported `tensorflow`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have installed stuff in the wrong order.

I run TensorFlow in Jupyter notebook all the time, I don't get your issue? If you have installed Anaconda and it is active eg when you type python, you get the Anaconda version of python, you just install TensorFlow with Pip (following instructions at TF.. ) and the fire up jupyter notebook do your imports including TF and you should be off and going, nothing special required. If you did it in the wrong order, eg TF then Anaconda just make sure that Anaconda is your default interpeter (as above) and re-install TF with pip. If that does not seem to fix whatever issue you are having, post more info...
 post your notebook info that tries to import TF?